# Numerically estimate $a^b$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, exponentiation, estimation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate non-integer exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62203/how-can-i-calculate-non-integer-exponents)

What is the most efficient way to estimate $a^b$ ($a > 0$) numerically?
My goal is not to use built-in math functions (like $e^x$ or $\log x$), i.e. only using +-*/.

I successfully accomplished this task by estimating $e^x$ and $\log x$ (below), because $a^b=e^{b\log a}$.

What I have done so far is estimated $e^x$ using the Taylor's series expansion:

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

$x^k$ can be found simply by multiplying $1$ by $x$ by $k$ times (because $k$ is an integer).

I then proceeded to estimate $\log$:

$$\log (z) = 2\operatorname{artanh}\,\frac{z-1}{z+1} = 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^{2n+1}$$

Putting these estimations together: $a^b=e^{b\log a}$, giving us an estimate that we can make to whatever accuracy is needed.

This method works to estimate exponents, but are there better and more efficient ways of doing this?

Comment: I would think the binomial series would make for a tidier estimate...

Comment: @J.M. How would that extend to non-integral $b$?

Comment: @Alex, Not too hard: $$(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (j-\alpha)$$

Comment: You could check the difficult-to-read code of function pow(x,y), which computes $x^y$, included in standard C libary here: http://pastebin.com/LDjS5mAR

Comment: I can't vouch that this is *the most* efficient method, but here's how I'd proceed: To estimate $a^b$ numerically, you're gonna have to find a rational approximation for $b$, say, by continued fractions or whatever. So let $b\approx \hat{b}=n/m$. You can calculate $c:=a^n$ efficiently by repeated squaring, though you'll have to watch out for overflow. Then you'll have to calculate $c^{1/m}$. This can be done efficiently via Newton's method, though you might get a failure of convergence.

Comment: @J.M. The question you posted and my question are asking different things.  The question asked in the link is about how non-integer exponents work and can be found.  I am aware of how to find non-integer exponents, and even added a method in my post.  I am trying to ask about efficient methods of estimation using a computer.

Comment: Yes, and I gave one such method in the answer to that question... so?

Comment: @J.M. Right... but it is not the same question, and your answer may not be the best for this question.

Comment: What part of it seems difficult for you? If you could say what you're going for, I can repurpose some of the things there as an answer here.